# Help understanding saving data please. Core data vs plist

Tags: core-data, plist

**Is every app that allows users to input data built with core data?**

I've built a "grocery list" type of table view app where you name the list and then in a detail view add items to the list. Simple.
What I don't get is this, based on an iphone development book the example saves the data to a plist using dictionaries.

I've learned that it works on the simulator but not the device because the data is saved to the application bundle not the document directory (which was new to me!)

On the device the app works great except-it won't HOLD the data.
Is core data or sqlite the only solution?
Is every app that allows users to input data built with core data?

Answer (score 3):

Note that your question as posed is incorrect, as it assumes that CoreData is tied to SQLite and is an alternative to plists.

CoreData is a framework for object lifecycle and graph management. It provides implementation of common tasks like changes tracking and propagation, consistency enforcement, data validation and so on.

The CoreData framework is a separate from the object persistence layer and can use different serialization implementations, including SQLite and XML (plists).

For more details, read [Core Data Programming - Persistent Store Features](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW1).

The decision whether you should use CoreData should be based on whether you need any of the features it provides. If you need to serialize simple object graphs, without consistency requirements, you can use standard NSDictionary to serialize your data in a simple plist file in any of the application-writable folders. Otherwise, use CoreData, and choose the proper persistent store based on the type of data you will be storing.

Comment: I'm not surprised my question is incorrect. That's part of my problem, I don't know enough yet to ask intelligently! :) It's bit embarrassing but I have to start somewhere. It appears serializing my data is the road to take. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen around the internet, you can use Core Data (which gives you the options of SQLite, atomic, and XML), you can use NSKeyedArchivers and NSKeyedUnarchivers (http://www.vimeo.com/1454094) or you can store the data inside the local application folder (possibly using a serialization method). It looks like Core data is the best solution, but a more complex one to implement. For a simple app, as yours is, I think serializing data and storing it in the local app directory would be perfect.

Comment: Does that mean that every app that accepts user input uses one of these methods?

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that your book is showing an example where user data is written to the app bundle. Actually, I'm a little surprised that that is even possible.

You should be able to write your data to an NSDictionary (or NSMutableDictionary) and then write that to your app's Documents directory, using -writeToFile:atomically:

Reading data back in should also be straightforward, using -initWithContentsOfFile:.

For someone just getting started, I would recommend keeping it simple. Working NSDictionary is very simple, though you have to manage things like the list of lists and how to name lists that are stored in Documents directory, etc.

Ultimately, using Core Data would probably be a better approach. It offers more flexibility and more power - but, as ever, those advantages come at a cost.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very important to the community in the respect that
you are asking a strategic question: *which technology do I use, when?*

**Core Data** is best for the day-to-day work of a list-based app. Core data is built to mirror the storage of data, similar to how databases work. Relational structures, sorting, key indexing and other row-based attributes are best supported by Core Data.

**Property Lists** (*.plist) is best suited to one-time updates to critical environmental settings. The user, for example, can optionally set .plist attributes through IOS Settings app. So passwords, account settings, email addresses, and configuration options can be set here nicely. This kind of data is very different from frequently-updated, transactional data.

**XML Persistence** is closely related to .plist, in that the property list (or .plist) is an xml file in itself. Hence, you could download a stream of xml data, then use it in your app using the same programming rubric as you would, adjusting a property list. Hence, receiving xml data from the web, or uploading such a list, maps nicely to xml persistence.

*AWS also proposed the AWS-Persistence library*, to support synchronizing your core data collections with their online databases. This could provide helpful by 1) having a user populate data locally via Core Data, then lazily/opportunistically uploading the list. For your purposes (grocery shopping list), this could provide immediacy to the user, while giving your server an interesting big-data opportunity (analyze user transactions, provide recommendations, sell ads, etc).

Hope this gets future visitors tapping into the wealth of what IOS provides -- peace!